# How to validate Vimeo video id?

Tags: javascript, vimeo

I need to create a regular expression which could validate a valid Vimeo video.

Accordingly to Vimeo API they use only numbers for Video Id, but they do not specify the length.

My regular expression so far `var regEx= /^[0-9]+$/;`

I would like to know:
- What is the allowed length supported by vimeo video id?
- How to modify my regEx?

Only article I found:
https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:267078

Comment: Try to get several IDs to see if there is a pattern. If there is any, then refine your regex. If there is not, then the only way I can think is using HTTP requests to see if a video is returned somewhere in the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of trying to invent a Vimeo Video ID validator, why don't you just use the [Vimeo developper API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/endpoints/videos#GET/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D) to check if the Vimeo ID is valid?

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}

+------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Http Status Code | Explanation                                      |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 200 Ok           |                                                  |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 403              | if the video does exist, but the view or the app |
|                  | requesting the video resource does not have      |
|                  | permission to access that video.                 |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 404 not found    | If the video cannot be found.                    |
+------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Check if you `(1)` or a user `(2)` owns a video:

```
(1) GET https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos/{video_id}
(2) GET https://api.vimeo.com/users/{user_id}/videos/{video_id}

+------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Http Status Code | Explanation                                          |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| 200 Ok           |                                                      |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| 404 not found    | If the video is not owned by the authenticated user. |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the API will return a 403 if the video _does_ exist, but the viewer or app requesting the video resource does not have permission to access that video. For example: a password protected video.

Comment: Password protected videos get 400 for me.